# Android Studio起動後にGradleの同期に失敗しましたと出る

Tags: android-studio

お世話になります。

今日からAndroidの開発に手掛けることになり、悪戦苦闘しています。

最新版だと思います。3.3.1です。JDK、Studioもインストールが終了し、
日本語化も行った後で、いざ入門用のサイトを見ながら学習を始めたのですが、
プロジェクトを立ち上げた直後に画像のようにGradleの同期に失敗しましたと
表示され、実行もできずにそこから先に進みません。

原因と対策をご教授ください。

初心者で申し訳ありませんが、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご利用中のネットワークがHTTP(S)プロキシ環境下であれば、Android Studioへのプロキシ設定が必要になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かプロキシはAutoで設定したのですが、それではいけないのでしょうか？

Comment: 明示指定してみてはいかが？ [Explicit is better than implicit.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: いろいろ試しましたが、原因はプロキシ云々ではない気がするのですが…。

Comment: 一般論として、追加で試した内容とその結果は質問文に追記された方が良いです。